# How to select specific data from text file in VB?

Tags: vb.net, select, text, arduino

I am making an Arduino weather station and I am outputting the data to a simple text file. But I want to make a like a year log of the highest and lowest temps. So my question is how can I select only the data between some symbols and then use it in VISUAL BASIC...For example my text file contains this string:"[29.11.2015 AT: 19:19:43] MR t. C:| 22.18 |Out t. C:| 7.36 |Aqu. H20 t. C:| 23.12 |Light(MR):| 1.63 | Door in MR:CLOSED!" and as you can see all the data is surrounded by these "|", can I make vb to get only this data and then compare it to previous one?

Comment: I suggest you add 20-30 text records to your post. Also make an attempt in code to read the file and to start parsing the data as best you can. A next logical design step is to create a database to hold your data. The database doesn't have to be high tech, even just a "flat" file that contains records separated by commas aka "CSV File."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Your delimiter will be the "|".